Present Unreal Conditional - mean future?
Here' are three sentences that I don't understand
These are from
https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/presentconditional.html#google_vignette
What I don't get is the website says all of these sentence are Present Unreal Conditional, but I think a couple of action verb can happen in the future.


If she were rich, she would buy a yacht.


Does this mean she would buy in the future or she would own now a yacht after buying?


If I moved to the U.S, I would live in Seattle


Does this imply I would move to the U.S in the future or I would would be in the state of having moved to the U.S and living there now?


If I won the lottery, I would buy a house


Does this mean the situation that I'm in the state of having won the lottery and being rich now or I would win the lottery in the future?

As you say yourself, it's a Present Unreal Conditional - not a future conditional (...I would be going to buy a yacht) nor a past conditional (...I would have bought a yacht. But because it's "unreal", it's "timeless" anyway.

OP has asked:


If she were rich, she would buy a yacht.
If I moved to the U.S, I would live in Seattle.
If I won the lottery, I would buy a house.


The Present Unreal Conditional (Second Conditional) does not inherently mean the future.
Instead, it describes hypothetical or imaginary situations in the present or future. Here's a breakdown of the conditional types:

Zero Conditional:
For scientific facts or general truths.
Example:
If you heat water, it boils.
First Conditional:
Describes possible or likely situations in the future.
Example:
If it rains, we will stay at home.
Second Conditional:
For unlikely or impossible situations in the present or future.
All three of OP's sentences belong to this group. The "if" clause is in the past tense, and the situation is imaginary:


If I were a bird (impossible).
If I won the lottery (unlikely but possible).
If I moved to the U.S.  (not impossible, but I don’t have plans now).


Third Conditional:.
For past regrets or criticisms, describing situations that cannot be changed because they refer to the past.
Example:
If I had studied harder, I would have passed the exam.


Conditional 2 doesn't have to be improbable, just imaginary in the current situation. Moving to the US might not be in your current plans, but plans change all the time.

@Barmar I edited my answer to include the various if condition.
